# Using Java For Loop to produce this outcome

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm fairly new at java programming and currently facing a coding problem. The goal is to write a for-loop that produces the following output:

```
10 * 1 = 10
9 * 3 = 27
8 * 2 = 16
7 * 1 = 7
6 * 3 = 18
5 * 2 = 10
4 * 1 = 4
3 * 3 = 9
2 * 2 = 4
1 * 1 = 1
```

Although I may be clear on getting the counting down and the amount of loops, what puzzles me is how do I get a loop to print 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1? Anybody could offer some help?

*edit*
I managed to solve my problem with the given wide array of solutions below. I was thinking along the lines of array but doubt my classes were that advanced (yet). Used the simple arithmetic solution and it worked perfectly! Will explore further! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hint: The answer will involve `something % 3`.  It will also involve adding and/or subtracting constants, but if you play with it a little I'm betting you can figure out a solution.  (OK, that's not the only answer--incrementing, comparing, and resetting as a posted answer suggests is possible.  But I'd usually use a solution involving `%`.)

Comment: `1,2,3,1,2,3,...` is `i % 3 + 1`. `1,3,2,1,3,2,1,...` is `(9 - i) % 3 + 1`

Answer (score 2):

As others said, you could use an array. No need for another variable to increment, though. To access the proper value, just use `i % 3` as the index. This will select from indices 0, 1, 2, then wrap back around as `i` continues to increase.

```
int [] mult = {1, 3, 2};
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int result = (10 - i) * mult[i % 3];
    System.out.println((10 - i) + " * " + mult[i % 3] + " = " result);
}
```

The `%` operator, by the way, is the modulus operator. In common practice, it is used to get the remainder when dividing two numbers. When you use `x % 3`, for increasing values of `x`, the result will always cycle through the values smaller than 3, which makes it perfect for use in cycling through the array of `[1, 3, 2]`.

Comment: Your array should be `{3, 1, 2}` to access `3` for `0`

Comment: @TAsk That depends on what `i` means, which he hasn't specified.  If `i==0` means the first line of the desired output, then the answer is correct.  If `i` means the first number that will be displayed on the line (i.e. `i==1` for the line `1 * 1 = 1`), then you're right.

Comment: @TAsk I updated it; midway through I changed the implementation but didn't change the loop to reflect that. `i` now refers to the first line of the loop, as ajb mentioned.

Comment: @ajb Right I was looking for the exact output *though*! BTW+1 looks good

Comment: @TAsk Added the `println` for the sake of completeness. :)

Answer (score 2):

No clunky arrays needed. Just a little old school math:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int j = 3 - ((i + 2) % 3); // j is what you want
}
```

And the whole thing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int j = 3 - ((i + 2) % 3); // j is what you want
  System.out.println((10 - i) + " * " + j + " = " + ((10 - i) * j));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A way to think about this:

```
     1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1
```

First notice that you have a 3,2 1 sequence repeating, you're just starting it partway through.

So 3, 2, 1 suggests using a % operator. Try it simply for 10, 9, 8, 7

```
10 % 3  = 1
9 % 3 = 0
8 % 3 = 2
7 % 3 = 1
6 % 3 = 0
```

So we're getting 2, 1, 0 appearing, and we want 3, 2, 1, so add 1

```
10 % 3  = 1 + 1 = 2
9 % 3 = 0 + 1 = 1
8 % 3 = 2 + 1 = 3
7 % 3 = 1 + 1 = 2
6 % 3 = 0 + 1 = 1
```

(we're now doing (n % 3) + 1 )

But we want to start the sequence at 1 not at 2, so adjust the n,

```
 (10 + 2) % 3  = 0 + 1 = 1
(9 + 2) % 3 = 2 + 1 = 3
(8 + 2) % 3 = 1 + 1 = 2
(7 + 2) % 3 = 0 + 1 = 1
(6 + 2) % 3 = 2 + 1 = 3
```

Hence the formula is

```
( (n+2) % 3 ) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
int num = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(num);
    num--;
    if (num == 0) num = 3;
}
```

Comment: Oops, you're right, thanks. I had that originally but I changed it for some reason.